# Eclipse - checking that all libraries are imported

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project that uses a lot of external libraries (mostly .jar files). I am using Eclipse Helios Service Release 2.

When something doesn't work, the problem is usually caused by missing jars or some problem with classpath. What I have to do, is to check that all necessary jars are correctly included in my classpath.

The problem is that I have several libraries imported + external jars (in case of libraries, the classpath only points to the directory with the jars) and Eclipse provides no easy way to search for included jars. If there was any kind of function that would work like this: "search for xyz.jar" and find if the jar with given name is already included somewhere, instead of manually controlling this, it would be a great help.

It would also help if Eclipse provided a function to sort all the jars and libraries by name instead of displaying them in the same order they are specified in path (I mean only in the project manager, of course).

**So my question:** is there an easy way to check these things or do I have to do that manually? I have cca 30 jars to include and cca 300 already there and this is a real pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a build environment, such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), to manage your dependencies for you. Then Eclipse does zero thinking on its own and your life becomes far more pleasant (particularly when the time comes to package your code for release).

I couldn't imagine managing 300+ dependencies any other way.

Comment: Absolutely. I just finished reconciling and looking up GAV coordinates for couple of hundred artifacts by SHA1 for an Ant built project. I published anything that wasn't available in public repos to an internal Nexus repo. I'd suggest looking at Gradle over Maven, it's a really excellent tool.